# NGINX reverse proxy failing with 404

Tags: nginx

I am setting up NGINX as reverse proxy.

Details:

nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

The following configuration works absolutely fine:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 172.31.1.248;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/SSL/self-public-key.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/SSL/self-private-key.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /pass/ {
                proxy_pass http://172.31.1.137:8000;
        }
}
```

However, with the upstream block, the requests fail with 404. I have tried both proxy_pass http://backend; and proxy_pass http://backend/;

```
upstream backend {
        server 172.31.1.137:8000;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 172.31.1.248;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/SSL/self-public-key.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/SSL/self-private-key.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /pass/ {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not certain if that's the problem. Why would it work with `proxy_pass http://172.31.1.137:8000;` and not with `proxy_pass http://backend;`?

Comment: Is there anything in your nginx logs?

Comment: The main difference between the two is the value of the `Host` header in the HTTP request to the upstream server. If the upstream server expects to receive requests with the `Host` header set to "`172.31.1.137`", it may not respond correctly if the `Host` header is set to "`backend`".

Comment: @CalumHalpin, nope, there is nothing in error log.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I don't think that's the problem. The upstream server is agnostic to `Host` header... I doubly checked, when NGINX returns 404, there is no request received by the upstream server. It is simply returned by NGINX.

Comment: What is the access log entry that returns the 404 response? You should test the response from your server with `curl -I  https://172.31.1.248/pass/`

Comment: With first configuration, the log entry is `172.31.1.248 - - [14/Jul/2019:09:01:51 +0000] "GET /pass/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5281 "-" "curl/7.58.0"`, and with the second configuration, the log entry is `172.31.1.248 - - [14/Jul/2019:09:02:21 +0000] "GET /pass/ HTTP/1.1" 404 30 "-" "curl/7.58.0"`